# error in calling 'npm install remix-ide -g' on win7 or centos

Tags: node.js, npm, solidity, remix

There are the logs as the below when I call the commad 'npm install remix-ide -g'

```
>gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: 进入目录“/home/ethereum/ethereum/remix-ide/node_modules/keccak/build”
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/keccak/src/addon.o
clang++: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by clang++)
clang++: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by clang++)
make: *** [Release/obj.target/keccak/src/addon.o] 错误 1
make: 离开目录“/home/ethereum/ethereum/remix-ide/node_modules/keccak/build”
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit 
(/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:209:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64
 gyp ERR! command "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin/node" 
 "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
 gyp ERR! cwd /home/ethereum/ethereum/remix-ide/node_modules/keccak
 gyp ERR! node -v v9.11.2
 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
 gyp ERR! not ok 
npm info lifecycle keccak@1.4.0~rebuild: Failed to exec rebuild script
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! keccak@1.4.0 rebuild: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the keccak@1.4.0 rebuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to 
install?
```

node -v v9.11.2
  npm -v 5.6.0
  That is the error log ,how to resolve it?